# Make login and signup work

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, realm

I'm currently in a project of making a service that has a web-app and an Android App. Currently the web team doesn't have the web services up and I need to implement login validation of forms and make it able for the user to sign up. I have tried with Realm but I don't really much understand it.
Any help?

Comment: what you have in login form..what have you tried?

Comment: Try using retrofit for webservice ..its much more stable and easy to use.follow given link for more info [http://square.github.io/retrofit/]

Comment: Well, Realm **is** a database, and not a validation library nor a REST API implementation :P

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this

http://sourcey.com/beautiful-android-login-and-signup-screens-with-material-design/

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

    @InjectView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.link_signup) TextView _signupLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });

        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Signup activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
            }
        });
    }

    public void login() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Login");

        if (!validate()) {
            onLoginFailed();
            return;
        }

        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO: Implement your own authentication logic here.

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // On complete call either onLoginSuccess or onLoginFailed
                        onLoginSuccess();
                        // onLoginFailed();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGNUP) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
                // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        finish();
    }

    public void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for login page user credentials validation, below code snippet may help you;

```
// validating email id
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

// validating password with retype password
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```